# live count of uniq lines

Tags: bash, shell, statistics

I've got a command that outputs a few different lines constantly (a stream), I'd like a live summary of the number of times each line has occurred (with a few seconds latency being acceptable).

for example if my command outputs the following:

```
apple
apple
apple
apple
banana
orange
banana
```

I'd like something like:

```
4 apple
2 banana
1 orange
```

and for the output to refresh every few seconds.

How might I achieve this? (rereading an entire log file will take too long, it has to be the output of a live pipe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use awk:

```
... | awk '{seen[$0]++} !(NR % 10) {print "======"; for (i in seen) print seen[i], i}'
```

This will keep a count of duplicates (`seen[$0]++`), and print them every ten input lines (`!(NR % 10)`). For example:

```
% % while sleep 1; do echo $((RANDOM % 10)); done | awk '{seen[$0]++} !(NR % 10) {print "======"; for (i in seen) print seen[i], i}'
======
1 0
1 1
3 3
1 6
2 7
2 9
======
3 0
3 1
1 2
3 3
1 4
2 5
2 6
3 7
2 9
======
3 0
3 1
2 2
3 3
2 4
5 5
4 6
3 7
2 8
3 9
...
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Could be done with a short `perl` script like:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
system qw(tput sc); # save cursor
$rc = `tput rc; tput ed`; # restore cursor and erase down
sub report {
  print $rc;
  print "$_: $c{$_}\n" for sort {
    ($c{$b} <=> $c{$a}) || ($a cmp $b)
  } keys %c;
  STDOUT->flush;
  alarm 1;
}
$SIG{ALRM} = \&report;
alarm 1;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  $c{$_}++;
}
report;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I accepted the awk answer because it's just a bit more readable than perl, but your answer is great too.

Answer (score 1):

`watch -n <seconds> "sort <file> | uniq -c"`

Should be about what you want. Runs `sort | uniq` every `<seconds>`.

Comment: Note the *(rereading an entire log file will take too long, it has to be the output of a live pipe)* in the OP's question.

Comment: hmm, that makes matters more complex. you will need to read the file in chunks and keep a rolling count of entries to be updated.